# JS Search Through a Nested JSON Structure where Deepness Increases Overtime

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to build an algorithm where if I have a 3 Layer Nested JSON structure but in the future this structure could be deeper. Like 5 layers. How can I account for this? I know how do this with fixed known layers but not with increasing layers.

Comment: How about you post some code and you explain what you tried

Comment: Have you tried using recursion ?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty standard tree-traversal problem.

Answer (score 0):

just to expand on what Juvian said (using recursion)

recursion is, essentially, a function that repeats itself. For JSON data, you would verify if a property is an object or array, and recursively call the function that traverses the JSON.

I have no code or data to work with, so here is a very simple example

```
var data = [
  {
    obj: {
      prop: 'some value',
      prop2: [
        'some value again'
      ]
    },
    value: 'string'
  }
];

function traverse(d) {
  var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(d),
      max,
      i;

      if(type === 'object Object') {
        max = Object.keys(data).length; // for objects
      } else if (type === 'object Array') {
         max = d.length; // for arrays
      }

  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    if (typeof d[i] === 'object') {
      // continue traversing 1 level deeper
      traverse(d[i]);
    } else {
      // do something with the value
    }
  }
}

traverse(data);
```